# When to create an in-memory object to manage repository records?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, mvc, repository, single-responsibility

Suppose I have a conceptual `Ledger` that is populated with `Line Items`.  Assume that `Line Items` themselves are stored in some type of persistent storage.  The ledger is shown to the user who can add/remove `Line Items`, or update variables inside a particular `Line Item`, such as price/quantity/description.

To handle this, for example, I could write a *single* class using Repository layer, call it something like `LineItemRepository`, and have it have functions like `loadLineItems()`, `addLineItem()`, `removeLineItem()`, `changeQuantityX()`, etc

To do its operations the class will need to be aware of things like

- `ledger_id` to load all the line items pertaining to that id, or to add a line item to the ledger
- `line_item.id` to remove/update a `Line Item`

[image]

It looks like with an aid of a `Controller` class, this will be all I need to trigger business domain events like "Add new Line Item", "Update Line Item Price", "Delete Line Item", etc.  I can also do things like "Find Sum of all Line Items with Description 'x' inside Ledger Y".

My Repository can essentially be a `Ledger`

**Question**

1) Is it okay to keep the concept of `Ledger` and `Line Item Repository` in a single class conceptually with respect to SRP and SOC?  If so how do I call this class?  `ItemRepositoryLedger`?

2) When do I need, why might I need, or do I ever need a separate `Ledger` object (in-memory representation of what is in the database, tasked with business functionality) from the `Repository` (tasked with actual database retrieval and storage functionality, presumably unaware of business functionality)  ?

I think that I could use such in-memory `Ledger` class for things like

- Load all line items at once into it and then not touch the database for a while until I really need to
- Add, edit update delete Line Items in the in-memory `Legder` as much as I need to before flushing them all into the database.  While I do so the database may become out of sync if it is updated by someone else (although in my specific case such cases will be rare...)
- Perform various many math operations on the Line Items without touching or stressing the database with each new way I want to sum things for example.

But the problems I see is that such `Ledger` will temporarily contain *duplicate* information of what is in the database.  That strikes me as "BAD".  But maybe not.  What if I want to load records and then do several various item pricing additions without hitting the database for each new one?

**Goal**

My goal for this question is to get a clearer understanding of here concepts of `Repository`, and in-memory structure such as `Ledger` fit in the MVC universe.

Current understanding is that Repository is only used to store/retrieve data and is not used to, for example, compute total price of LineItems.  A `Ledger` class would do that, after first using Repository to load the `Line Items` into memory.

But then I could also use Repository to sum the line items for me using SQL.  So I am a bit confused here...

**Further Thoughts**

I can take it a step further and ask .. Do I need an in memory `Line Item` object to represent the one in the database?  I guess I will need some object variable to store the data received from the database, to be able to show it in the View layer.  Without it, I have to call repository from my View.

Thus I probably need some structure/object/collection of variables to represent `Line Item`, until it is ready to be displayed in the View.

Should `Ledger` object follow the same logic?

Is `Ledger` essentially a `Controller` object, a manager of `Repository` in this case and not a separate domain-only entity?

Answer (score 1):

As your question is definitely more about high level design than about implementation, I would go back to the literal definition of a ledger (one of them, anyway), to get semantic hints :

"Ledger, n.: an account book of final entry, in which business transactions are recorded".

Whether it's about tracking and/or querying monetary unit transactions or about inventories of tangible (or not) items, I understand the essence of a ledger mostly as *one of* the interfaces / contracts implemented by (or delegated to) actual persistent stores of the domain's transactions (i.e., repositories).

IWO, the ledger(s) is/are interfaces that domain services will consume somewhere between themselves and the repositories (or implemented at either ends).

Theoretically speaking, I suppose a ledger interface could expose a set of pure functions, say, parameterized by start date / end date, transaction, item / account types, and whether one wants to see double-entry-based balances, etc -- but of course one may end up needing to break that purity, if computing such summaries on-demand just isn't feasible because they'd involve crunching data over too large datasets, etc.

'HTH,

Comment: thanks, just to note.. I may have picked a bad name for Ledger.  In my case it is a more of an Inquiry - a "live" modifiable state until it becomes an Order (in which case it becomes final).  Imagine a sales person working with a customer and adding/removing/updating line items on an `Inquiry`. That's a better representation of what I have in mind.